# Query on all nested docs inside a nested doc in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection with documents that look like this:

```
{ keyA1: "stringVal",
  keyA2: "stringVal",
  keyA3: { keyB1: { feild1: intVal,
                    feild2: intVal}
           keyB2: { feild1: intVal,
                    feild2: intVal}
          }
 }
```

Currently the [keyB1, keyB2, ...] set is 7 keys, same for all documents in the collection. I want to query the `intVals` on specific `fields` for *all* `keyB`'s. So, for example, I might want to find all documents where `field2` has value greater than 100 *regardless* of whcih `keyB` it falls in.

For any one specific `keyB`, I simply use the dot notation: `{"keyA3.keyB2.field2": {$gte: 100}}`. Right now, I have the option of looping over all `keyB`'s, but this may not be the case in the future where more `keyB` values can be added. I don't want to have to modify the code then, and would like to avoid harcoding those values in anyway. I also need the solution to be fairly fast, as the final deployment is expected to have over 20M documents.

How can I write a query that can "skip" the `keyB` field in the dot notation and just go through all the embedded docs?

FWIW, I'm implementing this in python using pymongo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first convert `keyA3` object to array and add new field with `$addFields`
then `filter` the new array to match field2 value is greater than 100
then query the doc that size of matched array is greater than 0 , then remove extra field we add

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "arr": {
        "$objectToArray": "$keyA3"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "matchArrSize": {
        $size: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$arr",
            "as": "z",
            "cond": {
              $gt: [
                "$$z.v.feild2",
                100
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      matchArrSize: {
        $gt: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "arr",
      "matchArrSize"
    ]
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/VumwL9y7Km1

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can see that this approach will work if I want to restrict results to a subset of keyB values as well (I can use $$z.k) which is great. The one question I have is, would the queries be faster if I were to restructure my documents to have arrays as keyA3 values? That way these operations could be done usign find() instead of aggregate().

Comment: I think yes, if you restructure your data i think is faster , but i think restructured  your data and send query in both of them to detect the speed of query